# ¿Cómo puedo verificar si una palabra está en un string?

Tags: c++

¿Cómo verificar si en un string está contenida una palabra en específico?

Comment: Tal y como está ahora es bastante amplia, deberías añadir más información: ¿usas alguna librería? ¿qué llevas hasta el momento? ¿con qué dificultades te estás encontrando?...

Answer (score 2):

Usa std::string::npos como en el siguiente ejemplo

```
if (string1.find(string2) != std::string::npos) {
    std::cout << "found!" << '\n';
}
```

Puedes mirar el siguiente enlace 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340281/check-if-a-string-contains-a-string-in-c

Comment: Si bien el enlace que compartes puede contener la respuesta a la pregunta, es mejor que incluyas las partes relevantes de la página en tu propio respuesta. De ese modo, si por cualquier motivo se rompe el enlace, tu respuesta seguirá teniendo sentido.